# Database connectionstring on per-LoggedIn-user basis

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a class library that contains hundreds of static methods and variable as follows…

```
public class General
{
        public static string Con { get; set; }

        public static string Func1()
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Con))
            {
                // My stuff here
            }
        }
        public static string Func2()
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Con))
            {
                // My stuff here
            }
        }

        public static string Funcn()
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Con))
            {
                // My stuff here
            }
        }
}
```

I referenced this class library to my ASP.Net Webform app and assign connectionstring from Global.asax’s Application_Start event

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        General.Con = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Con"].ConnectionString;
}
```

Everything works fine.

Now that I wanted to change database connectionstring on per-LoggedIn-user basis.

What I have tried:

I stored all user’s connectionstring info at one table in common database and mapped them to respective userIDs.

On Login button click, I could save connectionstring to session.

```
Session["Con"] = ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString();
```

In class library I used

```
Public static string Con = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Con"].ToString();
```

I get error : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
If I remove static, all my variable and methods gives an error: An object reference is required for the non-static
If I use new keyword here, error is “Cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead”.

Then I used

```
public static string Con()
{
        string Con = "";
        HttpContext httpContext = HttpContext.Current;
        if (httpContext.ApplicationInstance.Session.Count > 0)
        {
            if (httpContext.ApplicationInstance.Session["Con"] != null)
                Consd = httpContext.ApplicationInstance.Session["Con"].ToString();
        }
        return Con;
 }
```

It gives me error: Cannot convert from method group to string

Please help me out…

Comment: if the connection string is user specific why not save this connection string in the profile of each user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your class is static, which means there is a single instance, yet you want to change the connection on a user basis.

That is obviously not going to work. I would personally recommend you allow multiple instances of your class (non-static) and initialize each instance with the connection string as a parameter:

```
public class General
{
    private string _connectionString;
    public General(string connectionString)
    {
        _connectionString = connectionString;
    }    
}
```

You can then instantiate it once per session if you want, or simply instantiate it every time you need to use it. I would not recommend adding dependencies into the class (e.g. where the connection string comes to).

```
var data = new General(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString());
var result = data.Func1();
```

If for some reason, you need to keep the class static, you would need to either provide the connection string to the function so it can use it, or embed the logic to pull out the connection string from the session into the method:

```
public static string Func1(string connectionString)
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
            // My stuff here
    }
}
```

OR

```
public static string Func1()
{
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ds.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString()))
    {
        // My stuff here
    }
}
```

I would recommend passing the connection string as a parameter if you decide to go this route.

One last option if you wish to keep your class static would be to use a Configurator object that provides the connection string, in order to abstract the location:

```
public interface IConfigurator
{
    string GetConnectionString();
}

public class SessionConfigurator : IConfigurator
{
    public string GetConnectionString()
    {
        var connectionString = Session["Con"].ToString();
        return connectionString;
    }
}

public static class General
{
    public IConfigurator Configurator { get; set; }


    public static string Func1()
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Configurator.GetConnectionString()))
        {
            // My stuff here
        }
    }
}
```

Then upon application startup:

```
General.Configurator = new SessionConfigurator();
```